# Posting an array with curl_setopt

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

The attached code is returning "Notice:  Array to string conversion in...". Simply my array is being handled to the remote server as a string containing "Array" word. the rest of the variables are fine.

How can I pass my array `$anarray` without this problem?

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'anarray' => $anarray,
    'var1' => $var1,
    'var2' => $var2
 );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "MY_URL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772096/posting-multidimensional-array-with-php-and-curl

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/http_build_query)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
// The values of variables will be shown but since we don't have them this is what we get
```

You can then access it normally using the `$_POST` superglobal

Comment: `serialize` produces data in a completely wrong format for this operation

Comment: Why why why, why would you do that?

Comment: http_build_query is fine, those downvotes and comments must be to an older version of the answer

Comment: But since it has been edited after there was better answer with `http_build_query`....

Comment: It converts some integer to string which is a big problem on my end

Comment: ```
curl_setopt($ch,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                    json_encode($postData['data'])
                );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                   "cache-control: no-cache",
                   "content-type: application/json"
                ));
```
Worked for me

Answer (score 15):

The best way to accomplish what you're after is to use [`http_build_query()`](http://us.php.net/http_build_query).

Comment: This way cURL will generate a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` HTTP request which is fine unless you want to upload a file that requires a `multipart/form-data` request.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php description of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP
>   5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of the HTTP protocol, and the way curl_setopt function works, $anarray cannot be passed directly as an array.

The following statement:

> `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

takes an array of POST parameters and for each of them there must be a string name and a **STRING** value. You are passing an array value instead, so the PHP processor is forced to convert it to a string using some lame built-in algorithm, which incurs issuance of the before-mentioned notice ("Array to string conversion in...").

So, in order to properly pass that array ($anarray) to the other side, you have to take care of its encoding (into a string) yourself, as well as the other side has to take care of its decoding (from a string).

My approach in such situations is JSON. It is suitable enough in almost all cases. All you have to do is apply the following technique:

```
$data=array(
    'anarray'=>json_encode($anarray),
    'var1'=>$var1,
    'var2'=>$var2
    );
```

And then, on the other side of the connection you would retrieve the original array the following way:

```
$anarray=json_decode($_POST['anarray'],true); // true indicates for associative array rather than an object
```

Answer (score 0):

If $anarray is an array, as I suspect it is, it shouldn't be. Turn it into a string, by concatenating or whatever appropriate method.

Edit: See Eric Butera's answer.

Comment: I agree but what is missing the OP's question is also how is the data processed on the remote server. Without this information one cannot possibly say that json_encode() or serialize() or something else is the way to go.