# Send array as json and read that data

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I am encoding array as json and sending it by curl to other file:

```
$data = array(
  "authorizedKey" => "abbad35c5c01-xxxx-xxx",
  "senderEmail" => "myemail@yahoo.com",
  "recipientEmail" => "jaketalledo86@yahoo.com",
  "comment" => "Invitation",
  "forceDebitCard" => "false"
);

$data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/curl/1.php');
$headers = array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Problem is http://localhost/curl/1.php dont recieve any `$_POST` and I dont know how to operate on posted data.

http://localhost/curl/1.php output:

```
Headers:
  Host = localhost
  Accept = application/json
  Content-Type = application/json
  Content-Length = 166
GET:
 empty
POST:
 empty
```

Comment: Consider using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) instead of straight up `curl_*` functions.

Comment: Why are you sending it as JSON instead of normal POST data?

Comment: Bacause it depends of `1.php` which has that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending data by using request body, and you are supposed to get data by request body not $_POST super global. You can use following code to get whole data.

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data to show up in `$_POST`, don't encode it as JSON. Just pass the `$data` array to the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option, and don't send the `Content-type: application/json` header. `cURL` will then use the normal encoding for `POST` data, which PHP can convert into fields in the `$_POST` variable.

Comment: You have right, but it is not working with multidimensional array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8224117/1491895 shows how to convert a multi-dimensional array to a URL-encoded query.