# Posting multiple files to curl via CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl

I have an API I am trying to use that accepts multiple files in a single HTTP POST via multipart form data.

The problem is, the files have the same key (`images`). In Postman, the sample request looks like so:
[image: Postman example]

And in cURL this works too:

```
curl --location 'http://my-amazing-service.local' \
--form 'images=@"/Users/zach/Desktop/1.jpg"' \
--form 'images=@"/Users/zach/Desktop/2.jpg"' \
--form 'images=@"/Users/zach/Desktop/3.jpg"'
```

The problem is in PHP, `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` [does not take multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772096/posting-multidimensional-array-with-php-and-curl). For whatever reason, it works on my Mac I do anyway, but not inside a Docker container running Alpine Linux.

When I run the code below on Alpine Linux (in a Docker container), I can see from the `Content-Length` in the header is only `146`, meaning the binary contents of the image are not being included (my test image is about 50KB).

Is it possible to pass multiple files into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`? I'd rather not have to write the raw multipart POST body manually if possible.

```
$curl = curl_init();
      
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://my-amazing-service.local',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'images' => [
            file_get_contents('1.jpg'),
            file_get_contents('2.jpg'),
            file_get_contents('3.jpg'),
        ],
    ]
));
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($response === FALSE) {
    printf("cURL error: %s\n", curl_error($curl));
}
rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", $verboseLog, "</pre>\n";        
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `curl_file_create` to attach multiple files on your request, e.g:

```php
$file1 = curl_file_create('1.jpg');
$file2 = curl_file_create('2.jpg');

$data = array(
  'file1' => $file1,
  'file2' => $file2
);

$ch = curl_init('https://example.com/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Using your approach:

```php
$curl = curl_init();
      
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://my-amazing-service.local',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'file1'  => curl_file_create('1.jpg'),
        'file2' => curl_file_create('2.jpg'),
        'file3' => curl_file_create('3.jpg'),
    ]
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

In order to use a single `key` on the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, you have to use the same syntax used to pass an array in a query string:

```php
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://my-amazing-service.local',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'files[0]'  => curl_file_create('1.jpg'),
        'files[1]' => curl_file_create('2.jpg'),
        'files[2]' => curl_file_create('3.jpg'),
    ]
));
```

This is the same syntax that we use to pass an array of values on a query string:

```
http://example.com?name[0]=jon&name[1]=ari&name[2]=alex
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work if the API accepts `file1`, `file2`, and `file3` as the keys. But if the API accepts just `files`, it seems I can't pass an array of files into it?

Comment: @ZachRattner I've added another example

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work - the multipart POST data literally calls each key `files[0]` and as a result if the client is looking for multiple `files` parameters, the recipient doesn't get the data. Looks like the reason this is hard is the kets have to be unique, which the API isn't honoring right now. So I think there's no good solution apart from changing the API: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt

Answer (score 0):

After some more checking, it looks like the reason it's so hard to send a bunch of files in the same field name is because it technically violates [RFC 2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt):

> In forms, there are a series of fields to be supplied by the user who
> fills out the form. Each field has a name. Within a given form, the
> names are unique.

So this problem just went from a "Can I do it?" to a "Should I do it?"

I think the better solution is to reach out to the API maintainer and bring this up.