# curl_setopt Internal Server Error if I pass an array

Tags: php, curl, internal-server-error

I'm trying to call a web service and it was working when passing a json object to `curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $patientJS)` but the object sent didnt have the right structure son I pass now an array and I get an internal server error. If I print curl_error() it tells me

> Warning: curl_error(): 1044 is not a valid cURL handle resource

```
    $patient = array('nom' => $_POST['nom'], 
    'prenom' => $_POST['prenom'], 
    'login' => $_POST['email'], 
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'datenaissance' => $_POST['datenaissance'],
    'sexe' => $_POST['sexe']);


$patientJS = json_encode($patient);

$cSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://medicitussrv.herokuapp.com/enrollPatient');
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $patientJS);

$result = curl_exec($cSession);

curl_close($cSession);
```

This works but sends an object like

```
{ '{"nom":"Preciado","prenom":"Rodriguez","login":"artur_preciado@hotmail.com","password":"Medicitus1","datenaissance":"2017-09-06","sexe":"homme"}': '' }
```

pass an array:

```
    $patient = array('nom' => $_POST['nom'], 
    'prenom' => $_POST['prenom'], 
    'login' => $_POST['email'], 
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'datenaissance' => $_POST['datenaissance'],
    'sexe' => $_POST['sexe']);


$cSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://medicitussrv.herokuapp.com/enrollPatient');
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $patient);

$result = curl_exec($cSession);

curl_close($cSession);
```

This returns an Internal Server Error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Posting an array with curl\_setopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158138/posting-an-array-with-curl-setopt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `http_build_query` when you send array in curl it will create url encoded string

```
    $patient = array('nom' => $_POST['nom'], 
    'prenom' => $_POST['prenom'], 
    'login' => $_POST['email'], 
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'datenaissance' => $_POST['datenaissance'],
    'sexe' => $_POST['sexe']);


$cSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://medicitussrv.herokuapp.com/enrollPatient');
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($patient));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!